# Receiving a 404 response form requests.get

Tags: python-requests

Looking for some guidance on the following:

```
import requests
import json

class RESTConnector:

    def __init__(self, user, passwd, url):
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.url = url
        self.auth = user + ' ' + passwd

    def display_details(self):
        return '{} {} {} {}'.format(self.user, self.passwd, self.url, self.auth)

    def pull_data(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url, self.auth, timeout=3)
        print(type(response))
        print(response)

sub = RESTConnector('username1', 'password', 'http://some.url.com')

selection = input("Select data to query: ").lower()
if selection == 'subnet':
    print(sub.display_details())
    print(sub.pull_data())
else:
    print(f'Selection not recognised!')
```

Have used curl to test the credentials returned via display_details method and the data is returned as expected, however the above code returns the following:

```
$python "/Desktop/Python/RESTConnector.py"
Select data to query: subnet
username1 password https://some.url.com username1 password
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
<Response [404]>
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you have to pass the auth with a keyworded argument.

```
requests.get(url, auth=('user', 'passwd'), timeout=timeout)
```

Here's the implementation:

```py
import requests
import json

class RESTConnector:

    def __init__(self, user, passwd, url):
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.url = url
        self.timeout = 3

    def display_details(self):
        # Display all relevant class attribute.
        data = [f'{x}: {getattr(self, x)}' for x in self.__dir__() if not x.endswith('__')]
        return data

    def pull_data(self):
        response = requests.get(self.url, auth=(self.user, self.passwd), timeout=self.timeout)
        print('Task executed successfully:', response.ok)

sub = RESTConnector('username', 'password', 'http://some.url.com')

selection = input('Select data to query: ').lower()
if selection == 'subnet':
    print(sub.display_details())
    print(sub.pull_data())
else:
    print('Selection not recognised!')
```

Comment: This has been very helpful - thanks Federico! 

I was expecting response to contain json, but it contains None. One problem to the next :)

Comment: `Task executed successfully: 200`

So it's definitely making the successful connection, I guess it's something to do with how it's handling the data. Data at source is json, so I presumed it would be a straight forward pull

Comment: changing `response.ok` to `response.json()` and returning `response` got me what I need! :)

Comment: Because response.ok refers to the status code, while response.json() returns json in the response. Nice to hear it works now!